# Spider web everywhere in garden

Tags: plant-health

I am at a point where it is getting fustrated to see spider web everytime I go out in garden, and it get bigger then last one which I take off, today I saw big spider web from my shed from the cloth drying wire and to the ground, usually they form between shed and dyring wire.

What can I do to so spider don't make web in and around my garden. What attracts them? Is it because I haven't mowed the lawn in 4 weeks now? Does grass attract them?

Location wise, I m in North west (Manchester), UK

Comment: Why would you try to deter spiders from your garden? Unless you have arachnophobia (which would be something you should talk about with your healthcare provider), they are just a part of the complex system called “life” and “nature” your garden is a part of.

Answer (score 4):

You have an abundance of spiders and their webs since you will most likely have a similar abundance of aphids, greenfly and other plant pests that our arachnid pals eat before they chomp on your plants.

Don't worry, it will be their last hurrah until next year as soon as the colder autumn comes around.

This warm spell we are having in the UK (Sept 2023) is meaning the air is full of insect life and just like if KFC was giving away free chicken pieces there would be queue, so too does the insect life attract the spiders.

Comment: I like the KFC metaphor  what I really don’t want is to have spider webs in my clothes drying outside